# r for loop not advancing past first iteration

Tags: r, for-loop

This is all part of a larger code, but for some reason I'm having a weird bug with my for loop that I've never seen before. For some reason, the loop gets stuck after its first iteration, and won't progress through the remaining 27. No error, just an unfinished job. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
year = c(1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998)

catch = c(1138, 1183, 1380, 1672, 666, 973, 1118, 2900, 3599, 4218, 5124, 5559, 4891, 5751, 4525, 3592, 2682, 3617, 3458, 3173, 3550, 3987, 3084, 2515, 3162, 4125, 2311, 2694, 3250)

n = length(year)

ssq_CPUE = function(B0, r_input, p_input, K_input) {
  pred_B = rep(0, length(year))


  # scaling inputs
  B0 = B0*1000
  r_input = r_input/100
  p_input = p_input/1000000000
  K_input = K_input*1000
  # expected biomass

  pred_B[1] = B0
  for(i in 2:n){


      pred_B[i] = max(pred_B[i-1] + (r_input/p_input) * pred_B[i-1] * (1-(pred_B[i-1]/K_input)^p_input) - catch[i-1], 100)

    return(pred_B)
  }
}
```

When I input

```
ssq_CPUE(B0 = 42, r_input = 30, p_input = 1, K_input = 27)
```

I get the following vector:

```
 [1] 42000.00 35294.91     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
[12]     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
[23]     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
```

It correctly runs through the first iteration of the loop, but none of the remaining ones. Super weird and I have no clue why.

Comment: You need to move `return(pred_B)` outside of the for loop. `return()` ends the function, returning the current value as the result of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You have a small typo. The code should be:

year = c(1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 
         1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 
         1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998)

```
ssq_CPUE = function(B0, r_input, p_input, K_input) {
  pred_B = rep(0, length(year))


  # scaling inputs
  B0 = B0*1000
  r_input = r_input/100
  p_input = p_input/1000000000
  K_input = K_input*1000
  # expected biomass

  pred_B[1] = B0
  for(i in 2:n){
    pred_B[i] = max(pred_B[i-1] + (r_input/p_input) * pred_B[i-1] * 
                      (1-(pred_B[i-1]/K_input)^p_input) - catch[i-1], 100)
  }

  # This statement needs to be at the end of the function definition
  return(pred_B)
}
```

Comment: Wooooooow I'm an idiot haha. Super classic - tried using return() to help me debug (I was changing stuff around earlier) and it ended up sending me down a worse rabbit hole. Thanks!